# How can I count how many apple or banana that detected by camera?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, object-detection, counting

I found this code. This program uses a TensorFlow classifier to perform object detection and counting.

It draws boxes and scores around the objects of interest in each frame from the picamera.

It also uses a variable for counting the no. of objects in the frame.
How can I change in code to count targeted objects like bananas and apples that the camera detects?

```
######## Object counting using tensorflow on picamera #########
# Author: Vineeth Rajendran
# Date: 4/1/19
# Description: 
# This program uses a TensorFlow classifier to perform object detection and counting.
# It draws boxes and scores around the objects of interest in each frame from the picamera.
# IT also uses a variable for counting the no. of objects in the frame.

## Some of the code is copied from Evan Juras example at
## https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-on-the-Raspberry-Pi/blob/master/Object_detection_picamera.py


# Import packages
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse
import sys

# Set up camera constants
IM_WIDTH = 1280
IM_HEIGHT = 720
#IM_WIDTH = 640    Use smaller resolution for
#IM_HEIGHT = 480   slightly faster framerate

# Select camera type (if user enters --usbcam when calling this script,
# a USB webcam will be used)
camera_type = 'picamera'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--usbcam', help='Use a USB webcam instead of picamera',
                    action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.usbcam:
    camera_type = 'usb'

# This is needed since the working directory is the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append('..')

# Import utilites
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# Name of the directory containing the object detection module we're using
MODEL_NAME = 'ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_05_09'

# Grab path to current working directory
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to frozen detection graph .pb file, which contains the model that is used
# for object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'data','mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

# Number of classes the object detector can identify
NUM_CLASSES = 90

## Load the label map.
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when the convolution
# network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.
# Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a
# dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)


# Define input and output tensors (i.e. data) for the object detection classifier

# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

# Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

# Number of objects detected
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

# creating a fucntion 
def object_counting()
    # Initialize Picamera and grab reference to the raw capture
    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = (IM_WIDTH,IM_HEIGHT)
    camera.framerate = 10
    rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(IM_WIDTH,IM_HEIGHT))
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    for frame1 in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",use_video_port=True):

        totalcount=0

        # Acquire frame and expand frame dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
        # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
        frame = np.copy(frame1.array)
        frame.setflags(write=1)
        frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

        # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
        (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
            [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
            feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

        # Visualizing the results of the detection
        vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            frame,
            np.squeeze(boxes),
            np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
            np.squeeze(scores),
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            line_thickness=8,
            min_score_thresh=0.40)

          # Updating totalcount
        totalcount=totalcount+num

          # Displaying the number of objects detected using the totalcount variable
        cv2.putText(frame,"Count"+str(totalcount) ,(10, 35),font,0.8,(0, 0xFF, 0xFF),2,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,)

        # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
        cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

        # Press 'q' to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

        rawCapture.truncate(0)

    camera.close()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

object_counting()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above use a model from TF Object Detection API.
This model was trained on a dataset named COCO (http://cocodataset.org/#home)
This data set contain many general classes (overall 80 classes for detection), you can find out what classes exist in the labels files called from the script:

```
# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'data','mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')
```

You will see a lot of classes (person, car, bus, dog ...), and even 'orange', and 'banana'.
So while you script counts how many objects the detector detected, you are only interested in specific classes(labels):

```
231 item {
232   name: "/m/09qck"
233   id: 52
234   display_name: "banana"
235 }
...
246 item {
247   name: "/m/0cyhj_"
248   id: 55
249   display_name: "orange"
250 }
```

So, class 52 is banana and class 55 is orange.

What left to do is take the results from the following lines:

```
# Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})
```

Look on your resulted **classes**, and count how many times 52 appeared and how mane times 55 appeared. 
(a simple command like: numpy.sum(classes == 52) should do the trick)

Comment: okay bro  i got you, but what is the code for counting those specific classes ?